# How to get PowerShell colors when running as admin

Tags: windows-8, conemu

I'm trying to setup conemu and like the transparent window feature and being able to specify color scheme. It works great with transparent and color window when I'm not in admin mode. This is what I have as a prefined task

```
cmd  -new_console:a

powershell  -new_console:a
```

Everything starts as expected but the windows don't get the color I expect. If I remove `-new_console:a` I get transparency, but I'm not administrator anymore. So what can I do?

**UPDATE 2:**

New log files: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ntku1xfkxhnl2nz/0nCXg_VmYP

Settings file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/byvpk1kdkhaxp1u/conemu.reg

**UPDATE:**
Some more information. I'm running Windows 8 on a Macbook Pro Retina if that could be causing an issue.

I've updated the title and subject since the problem wasn't the transparency; it was that the color was black, but the black color didn't have the same transparency "effect" so I didn't see that I had transparency. However, there is still the problem with color. I have setup powershell.exe to user powershell color scheme, but it is still white on black.

I can use a work around by always running conemu as administrator, but I would like to know how I can solve it without that.

**UPDATE:**

Screen capture is here of the behavior: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6cu06ecwy2baa3/conemu.mp4

Log file:

```
16:28:13.485 ConEmu 130427[32] log[1]
16:28:13.488 Startup info
    OsVer: 6.2.9200.x64, Product: 1, SP: 0.0, Suite: 0x100, SM_SERVERR2: 0
    CSDVersion: , ReactOS: 0 (), Rsrv: 0
    DBCS: 0, WINE: 0, ACP: 1252, OEMCP: 850
    Desktop: Winsta0\Default
    Title: conemu  /log
    Size: {0,1},{100,100}
    Flags: 0x00000000, ShowWindow: 1, ConHWnd: 0x00000000
    Handles: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Active HKL: 0x041D041D
GetKeyboardLayoutList: 0x04140414 0xF0C90414 0x041D041D 0x04090409
CmdLine: conemu  /log
ExecMod: C:\Program Files (x86)\ConEmu\ConEmu.exe
WorkDir: C:\Program Files (x86)\ConEmu
PathEnv: C:\Program Files (x86)\ConEmu\ConEmu;C:\Program Files (x86)\ConEmu;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\dev\utils\;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\;C:\Chocolatey\bin;
ConFont: 932    *ＭＳ ゴシック    949 *굴림체    00  Consolas    0   Lucida Console  950 *細明體    936 *新宋体
Modules:
  00400000-0054EFFF   14F000 C:\Program Files (x86)\ConEmu\ConEmu.exe
  77420000-77576FFF   157000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  753B0000-754DFFFF   130000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.DLL
  74C00000-74CA5FFF    A6000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
  76EF0000-77005FFF   116000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USER32.dll
  74AD0000-74B7DFFF    AE000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ADVAPI32.dll
  75680000-76745FFF  10C6000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHELL32.dll
  76AD0000-76BE8FFF   119000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ole32.dll
  76D10000-76E0CFFF    FD000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\GDI32.dll
  74120000-74127FFF     8000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
  76CD0000-76D0FFFF    40000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHLWAPI.dll
  73CF0000-73EE7FFF   1F8000 C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9200.16579_none_8937eec6860750f5\COMCTL32.dll
  74D20000-74DA8FFF    89000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\COMDLG32.dll
  740E0000-74100FFF    21000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
  75140000-751CAFFF    8B000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\OLEAUT32.dll
  6C5C0000-6C5D1FFF    12000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NETAPI32.dll
  76E20000-76ED0FFF    B1000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcrt.dll
  76750000-76783FFF    34000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
  770F0000-7719BFFF    AC000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\RPCRT4.dll
  75540000-75675FFF   136000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
  740B0000-740D9FFF    2A000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
  6DEA0000-6DEAAFFF     B000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\netutils.dll
  6C520000-6C53BFFF    1C000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\srvcli.dll
  6C5B0000-6C5BFFFF    10000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wkscli.dll
  74A50000-74A6BFFF    1C000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
  744B0000-74524FFF    75000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHCORE.DLL
  74A40000-74A48FFF     9000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
  6D4F0000-6D501FFF    12000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SAMCLI.DLL
  749E0000-74A30FFF    51000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
  74CB0000-74CCFFFF    20000 C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
  76BF0000-76CCCFFF    DD000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCTF.dll
  747C0000-747C6FFF     7000 C:\PROGRA~2\NVIDIA~1\3DVISI~1\nvStInit.dll
  74A70000-74A75FFF     6000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\PSAPI.DLL
  74710000-747B2FFF    A3000 C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6871_none_50944e7cbcb706e5\MSVCR90.dll
  73F60000-73FE7FFF    88000 C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
  73C90000-73CA8FFF    19000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
  74490000-744A0FFF    11000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
16:28:13.568 Settings::LoadSettings
16:28:13.571 Loaded pos: {-3,-3}, size: {97,42}
16:28:13.581 SettingsLoaded
16:28:13.584 Registering fonts
16:28:13.586 SingleInstanceArg
16:28:13.588 isFirstInstance
16:28:13.589 Waiting for RunSingleInstance
16:28:13.591 Passed to first instance, exiting
```

Comment: All works as expected on my side. Need for more information: run "ConEmu /log", make screenshot of full screen, attach screenshot and log files (created on desktop or in program folder).

Comment: Hmm... tried it on another computer at work with windows 7 and it works as expected. The computer I had the problem with was my macbook pro with windows 8 installed. I can try it more after work later today.

Comment: @Maximus, I've updated the question quite a lot. The problem wasn't the transparency, it was the color mainly. But it is still a problem.

Comment: Without your exported settings I can only guess. "App distinct"?

Comment: I was so in the mode of trying to figure it out myself so I totally forgot your comment about screenshot and log file, I'll do that later today. I notice now that the conemu at work always starts in admin mode which is weird, I am administrator but I haven't checked that it should start in admin mode.

Comment: @Maximus, I've added logs and a screen capture of the behavior.

Comment: `Passed to first instance, exiting` - that is wrong log, from autoexited instance. I need logs from your running instance. And export of your ConEmu settings. Also, comment please, what are you doing on your video.

Comment: in the video I first start conemu two times just clicking it, and as you see the background is black. When right clicking and starting as admin the last time it is opening as I expects and the background is blue. I've updated the post with links to new log files and settings.